# don't have permission to access mac HD on dual boot MBP

Tags: dual-boot, permissions, mac

I've tried changing the sharing permissions in OSX to allow my ubuntu 12.04 to access the mac hd, but it still says i don't have permission to do so while on the ubuntu boot. I also tried to find out something about file headers for OSX or whatever the command *-id* is supposed to do in command prompt but the command apparently isn't a valid command.

Answer (score 0):

Terminal is a good place to start. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> to launch it or <kbd>Super</kbd> click on th **A** (Application icon) and type `terminal` into the input field.

The way to change permissions is to use the `gksu` command to gain root privileges along with a file manager so type the following in to Terminal:

```
dksu nautilus
```

This will start nautilus as the root (You may need to enter your password) You can then go to the folder you want to gain access to and with a Right Click>Permissions, gain control of the folder

**BUT BE VERY CAREFUL WHICH FOLDERS YOU TAKE PERMISSIONS AWAY FROM ROOT! IT CAN KILL YOUR SYSTEM**